# Does $A\sin b=B\sin b+C\cos b$ imply $C=0$?

Tags: trigonometry

If $\cos b$ and $\sin b$ are both non-zero, does $$A\sin b=B\sin b+C\cos b \quad\implies\quad C=0$$ because there is no $\cos$ term in the l.h.s. of the equation?

Thank you!!

Comment: Not necessarily. We could have $\cos b=0$.

Comment: Unless this is an identity for all $b$.

Comment: @Matt Samuel, oh yes I forgot to mention that $$cosb$$ value is not zero.

Comment: Thanks for the edit!!

Comment: What, for example, if $b=\pi/4$, $A=3$, $B=2$, $C=1$?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin oh no, it is for a "particular" b with the values of the constants being anything!! But the fact is the $cos$ and $sin$ terms definitely do not equal to zero

Comment: I removed your "stupid question" introduction, because this is not a stupid question. ... *If*, as @MattSamuel suggests, you are asserting that the same $A$, $B$, $C$ are supposed to work *for all* $b$, then the implication is true. (This is because of $sin x$ and $\cos x$ are "linearly independent" functions, which is a non-trivial property.) If you aren't asserting the same $A$, $B$, $C$ work *for all* $b$, then it's easy to generate examples: take any $A$ and $B$, and then (for $\cos b \neq 0$) you can *solve* for $C$; it'll be $0$ only if $\sin b=0$ or $A=B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\sin b \ne0 $ and $\cos b \ne0 $, you can divide by $\sin b $ to get
$$ A = B  + C\cot b$$
Rearranging this gives 
$$ C = (A-B)\tan b $$
So $$A\sin b=B\sin b+C\cos b $$ does not imply $C=0$ unless $A=B$, as it is given $\sin b \ne0 \iff \tan b \ne 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the neat answer and thanks to everyone for the response!! But just out of curiosity, what could be the value of constants? Like would they be really nos., trigonometric functions at a given point, or complex nos.? I am guessing trigonometric functions at given point.

Comment: If $\cos b$ and $\sin b$ are non-zero,  $A$ and $B$ can take any value you like - there will always be a value for $C$ which can be calculated which will satisfy the equation.

Comment: even complex?..............

Comment: Yes - there is no reason why complex coefficients would behave differently; $ C=(A−B) \tan b$ is defined for all $b$ such that $\tan b$ is defined.