# Trigonometry: Value of constants

Tags: trigonometry

I have this equation where $A\sin b=B\sin(a-b)$
I have to find the value of A and B. Is there any other way except for assuming $A=\sin(a-b)$ (if it's even correct in the first place) even though it is giving me the answer I want?
Note the $\sin$ values are not zero neither the constants. The a and b are specific points, nos. radians,...
edit:$sin(a)$ and $sin(a-b)$ is a constant value except zero.

Comment: You mean a value for $A,B$ so that regardless of $a,b$, the equation holds?

Comment: @Don Thousand, yes, yes. That's correct!!

Comment: If that's correct then $\sin(a-b)$ does not have a constant value, so setting $A=\sin(a-b)$ will not give you a constant.

Comment: @David K I edited the question, sorry.

Comment: In light of this question and your [previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3319236/409), perhaps you could explain what you're trying to accomplish overall. There may be a general principle here that can save you from having to post multiple questions.

Comment: @Blue Okay, so the thing is it's a physics quantum problem but the problem is mathematical so instead of completely asking it at physics stackexchange and getting it reported off topic I decided to put my doubts over here.

Comment: @Blue I am so sorry if it's against the rules...

Comment: When you ask only about little bits and pieces of a bigger question, without showing the context in which your little questions arose, you are very likely to get answers that are not useful to apply to your larger question. It is a waste of time for the people who answer and can be worse than a waste of time for you.

Comment: @David K do you recommend editing the question or posting a new one even though it's actually from physics but is largely related to maths?

Comment: @Korra: You've done nothing wrong. :) It simply occurred to me, since your questions seemed somewhat similar, that knowing the bigger picture might help us help you better. Please include the physics problem in the body of your question, and then (if it's not already obvious) point out the aspect of the that problem that prompted this specific question.

Comment: I agree with Blue's comment. The best purpose of comments is to help improve a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A\sin b=B\sin(a-b)\iff \frac {A}{B}= \frac {\sin (a-b)}{\sin b}$$

$$A=\lambda  \sin (a-b)$$ and$$ B=\lambda \sin b$$ where $\lambda $ is an arbitrary real number.

Comment: So $$λ=1$$ should be fine? Right?

Comment: @Korra Again, yes, it's fine _unless it isn't fine._ Whether it is good or no good to make that assumption depends on what you need the values of $A$ and $B$ for.

Comment: @David K thanks again!! I am just really doubtful about this whole thing...

Answer (score 3):

If you have specific values of $a$ and $b$, plug them into

$$A\sin(b) = B\sin(a-b) \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

to get something like

$$Ac_1 = Bc_2 \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

where $c_1 = \sin(b)$ and $c_2 = \sin(a-b)$. If $c_1$ and $c_2$ are not $0$, then there is no unique value for $A$ and $B$. Instead, you can choose one of the values and get the other one in terms of the first. In particular, you can assume a value for $B$ and get $A = \frac{Bc_2}{c_1}$, or assume a value for $A$ and get $B = \frac{Ac_1}{c_2}$.

Comment: Meaning my approach of assuming the values is correct?

Comment: @Korra You can assume the values you mention of $A = \sin(a-b)$ and $B = \sin(b)$, with this giving you a valid  answer. However, it's not the only answer. As I explain above, there are many possible answers. The main issue is you have $2$ variables, i.e., $A$ and $B$., but only $1$ equation to relate them.

Comment: so I guess since I am getting the answer I want it's pretty fine. Thanks!!

Comment: @Korra It's fine unless you need the answer to be uniquely determined. For example, if someone says, "given these equations, is $A$ less than or greater than $2$," then the correct answer is _not_ "less than." You could say "there's no way to know" or "what would you like the answer to be?"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $a, b, A,$ and $B$ are parts of a triangle (which imposes some restrictions on their values) by Law of Sines we have

$$\frac{\sin a}{A} = \frac{\sin b}{B}.$$

If we un-cross-multiply your equation, we have

$$\frac{\sin (a-b)}{A} = \frac{\sin b}{B}.$$

We conclude that $\sin a = \sin(a-b).$

Under our restrictions, this forces $b=0$.

Comment: No they aren't. Thanks for the effort, though!!